# ios Auto-Layout UIView on 3.5 changing height on 4.0 inch

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I Have an UIView in a ViewController placed at the bottom of a 3.5 Inch Layout.

In a 4.0 Inch Layout, the UIView change its Height(im Using Auto-layout -> reset to Suggested Constraints in myViewController) but i dont want change the height. I Need only to change the Y coordinate to place the View At the Bottom again in 4.0

Any Suggestions?

Layout on 3.5 Inch(and the position what i want the bottomBar without any resizing)
http://postimg.org/image/pxbqz770h/

Layout on 4.0 Inch
http://postimg.org/image/v419qxr37/

Comment: Set your own constraints.  Click on the view and set a bottom constraint.  If you don't want to change the height, set the height constraint too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on Douglas's comment, you want to set your own constraints manually. Suggested constraints are often handy, but not always 100% correct.

Among the key-constraints you'll want are the "view to bottom" and the height constraint"

On storyboard, there's a "pin" button. Click that, and you can set the necessary constraints here.

Comment: Setting my own constraints resolved to problem. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Last piece of advice I always give about autolayout. Don't be afraid to delete constraints and set/reset them. It's the fastest way to wrap your head around it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use constraints, this will shrink or grow the view depending on the device. On Interface builder, click on your UI object, then click on the constraint pin tool. Insert a constraint for the top and the bottom.  Take a look at this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-autolayout/pin-constraints.html